# Where can I download powersports oem microfiche schematics?

Tags: data-request

Where can I download powersports oem microfiche schematics? I have wrote to a few companies and they smaller ones have provided me with some data. But what about the others?

Comment: who specifically have you contacted, and what were the responses?

Comment: They where small small companies like gasgas the others where some chinese bike companies that gave it to me. As for honda, bmw, harley, your bigger powersports all I get a is a bs answer. I think its one of those things where I just have to keep on asking.